Is it possible to hardware accelerate spice with an nvidia gpu?
It is possible to use virgl with an nvidia gpu:
<graphics type="egl-headless">
  <gl rendernode="/dev/dri/renderD128"/>
</graphics>
<video>
  <model type="virtio" heads="1" primary="yes">
    <acceleration accel3d="yes"/>
  </model>
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x01" function="0x0"/>
</video>

however using this approach, you cannot have gl enabled in spice, if you try to enable it in any way it just gives you this error:
Error changing VM configuration: unsupported configuration: multiple OpenGL displays are not supported by QEMU

So we have an nvidia gpu accelerated opengl display that works for virgl and a laggy spice display that sorta makes the former a moot point. Is there any configuration arrangement where I can have the spice display opengl accelerated with the nvidia gpu powering virgl? Or even just redirect spice to use that egl-headless display?

Current answer to the question is No, there is a git issue for this here: https://github.com/virt-manager/virt-manager/issues/632
